# Golang X509 Keypair ignored

Tags: go, ssl

We are using Golang to communicate with an external service using HTTPS. When attempting the request using cURL, we get success. When using Go, the certificate appears to be ignored, yielding a 403 from the external service.

We have been unable to spot any differences in the cURL-request vs the Golang code. Can somebody help us find a difference?

The cURL-request gives us a proper JSON response. The Go code gives:

```
2020/09/07 15:05:57 request error: perform request: api response: 403 Forbidden
```

Working cURL-request (user agent for debug purposes):

```
curl -X GET --http1.1 -i -v --key client.key.pem --cacert ca.pem --cert client.pem "https://[redacted]/path/to/endpoint" -H "Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" -H "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)" -H "X-Identifier: [redacted]" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Connection: Keep-Alive"
```

Golang code yielding a 403:
(note: files `ca.pem`, `client.pem` (cert) and `client.key.pem` must be in same directory. run script as `go run catest.go --url "https://[redacted]/path/to/endpoint" --identifier [redacted]`)

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // Get URL to call.
    url := flag.String("url", "", "URL to call")
    identifier := flag.String("identifier", "", "the X-Identifier value")
    flag.Parse()

    if url == nil || identifier == nil || *url == "" || *identifier == "" {
        log.Fatal("'url' and 'identifier' arguments must be provided")
    }

    // Set up certificates
    caPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read 'ca.pem' in current directory: %v", err)
    }

    clientPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read 'client.pem' in current directory: %v", err)
    }

    clientKeyPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client.key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read 'client.key.pem' in current directory: %v", err)
    }

    // Make calls.
    client, err := configureClient(caPEM, clientPEM, clientKeyPEM)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to setup client: %v", err)
    }

    _, err = performRequest(client, *url, *identifier)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("request error: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("request successful")
}

func configureClient(caCertPEM, clientCertPEM, clientKeyPEM []byte) (*http.Client, error) {
    // Load the CA certificate.
    caCertPool, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("configure client: load cert pool: %w", err)
    }

    // Append root CA cert from parameter
    ok := caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCertPEM)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("configure client: could not append ca certificate")
    }

    // Load the client certificate.
    clientCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(clientCertPEM, clientKeyPEM)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("configure client: load client certificate: %w", err)
    }

    // Setup HTTPS client.
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:       caCertPool,
        Certificates:  []tls.Certificate{clientCert},
        Renegotiation: tls.RenegotiateOnceAsClient,
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    return client, nil
}

func performRequest(client *http.Client, u, identifier string) ([]byte, error) {
    if client == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: nil client")
    }

    // Prepare request
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, u, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: create GET request: %w", err)
    }

    // Add same headers as cURL.
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
    req.Header.Add("X-Identifier", identifier)

    // Send request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: client do: %w", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    switch resp.StatusCode {
    case http.StatusOK:
        break
    case http.StatusUnauthorized:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: api response: unauthorized")
    case http.StatusBadRequest:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: api response: bad request")
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: api response: %v", resp.Status)
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("perform request: read response body: %w", err)
    }

    return data, nil
}
```

Comment: A few things: 1) why are you calling `NameToCertificate`? 2) why are you enabling renegotiation, this is often terribly broken 3) trim down the headers, you probably don't need anything other than `X-Identifier` 4) you're adding the custom CA cert to the system pool. any reason you don't just use the custom CA directly? 5) check the docs to the API in question, if possible, link to them 6) I assume there were no errors 7) what does `resp.Status` say?

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1) I've tried removing it as well, no difference. 2) Omitting or setting "Never" gives `local error: tls: no renegotiation` 3) I want to recreate the working request as exactly as possible. Fewer headers gives same result. 4) Their CA is based on a third party CA, so I want the chain. 5) It's a locked one, so I am unable to give out those docs, unfortunately...

Comment: It's possible it's a renegotiation problem, either the server or the Go lib have a problem with it, but it's really hard to tell. Try setting the `tls.Config.GetClientCertificate` callback to see if it gets called multiple times. You can also try returning the client certificate from it (that's unlikely to work, but you never know). Also, please see questions 5) and 6) from my initial comment (it was edited). Also try using `RenegotiateFreelyAsClient` for renegotiation.

Comment: It's only called once, using both `RenegotiateFreelyAsClient` and `RenegotiateOnceAsClient`. Also tried returning the client cert, which made no difference. Reg. other questions: 5) Correct - no errors (unless I fail to catch one somewhere). 7) `resp.Status` stays `Forbidden`.

Comment: If you have access to server logs (it sounds like an internal application), that might help you to at least see the server-side error. Beyond that, you could try instrumenting the standard library to log more details. Or dump the session keys and analyze the traffic with wireshark.  Also make sure you're running the latest Go version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server logs, but I'll try contacting the service provider to see if they can help me troubleshoot. I'm running Go version 1.14.1 I'll try updating to 1.15.1 and see if it makes a difference!

Comment: But otherwise, you don't see anything with the code that is erroneously implemented from my part?

Comment: I don't, sorry. I pointed out all the slightly odd things in my first comment but it was unlikely to change anything.

Comment: I'd also try to use `openssl s_client -debug` with your keypair and its options allowing to selectively allow/deny certain versions of TLS (and SSL, but this hardly matters).

Comment: There may definitely be a problem with that - I know that the server only accepts HTTP/1.1. However, that gave an error before, so I assumed that it has been negotiated already.

Comment: Worth noting as well is that the request works with cURL, SoapUI and Safari, but not in Chrome, Firefox or Postman. Very strange issue. I'm using Mac OSX Catalina (10.15.6).

Comment: The mix makes it sound like a misbehaving TLS implementation on the server side (or just obscure enough that not all clients handle it). I'm not sure we can help more without details of the server, so your best bet is probably with the owners/authors.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for you help, Marc! Will contact their support to move forward.